# RPC-Literal in .net Core 3.1

Tags: .net, .net-core, soap

New to soap.

Trying to upgrade an older framework project into .net core 3.1 consuming an RPC Literal soap service.

I don't think it matters (shouldn't matter) but the called service is java.

When building the reference straight from the wsdl everything generates fine but I get the error

"InvalidOperationException: Namespace='url to service' is not supported with rpc\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified."

I read to change the XmlSerializerFormatAttribute from rpc to document.

```
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.**Document**, SupportFaults=true)]
```

This prevents the exception from being thrown and I can see the request go out in fiddler with the correct/valid response from the called service. however, Without an exception being thrown the response is not deserialized and in is returned as null to my code.

Any thoughts on what could cause this? how do I fix it?

I've tried pulling in the reference.cs file from the framework project. It has a few differences specifically around how it handles the inheritance structure of the return (it has a base error class) but I get a RTE saying the configuration api isn't available anymore.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I have the same error

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?
I have the same problem and symptoms when calling SOAP from .Net 6